# Not able to connect to go grpc server using python client

Tags: python, go, grpc

I have a grpc server running in Go. I am not able to call a method into it using the python client. Not sure what is going wrong. I get the following error

`_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.UNIMPLEMENTED, method: /com.test/myMethod)>`

Any idea what could have gone wrong? The Go client is able to communicate properly.

Also I generated the stubs following the instructions https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/python.html

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I../../protos --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. ../../protos/route_guide.proto
```

Once I got the py files, I removed the proto files and zipped the package. This zipped package is what I am using for my python client. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: hard to tell, as we can see neither server nor client code

Comment: Agreed; please share all code necessary to demonstrate the problem (assuming you're able to do so without sharing anything private or confidential).

Comment: Need to see to code to actually provide a proper answer but as far as I can see, there seems to be a missing method on the server code interface

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes I get `StatusCode.UNIMPLEMENTED` when the version of the protocol buffer files used by the client and the by server are in a inconsistent status.

For example I made a change in the proto buffer file in the server but I forgot to change the proto buffer file in the client.

I don't know if this can help but sometime it happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried to reproduce your issue and found that:

The names of class that we implement in `server.py` and the class we add to the gRPC server must be the same.

Example:

```
class SubClassImplemented(ExtendedClassGenerated):
    ...

def serve():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    add_<name>_to_server(SubClassImplemented(), server)
```

Here,

`SubClassImplemented` - the class inherits from the generated class, must be added to the gRPC server.

`ExtendedClassGenerated` - generated class present in `<name>_pb2_grpc.py`

`add_<name>_to_server()` - method present in `<name>_pb2_grpc.py`, used to add your logic to a gRPC server.

*Hope this helps!!*
I've also added a screenshot for the same.

[add server class to gRPC server screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvzBR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check that your proto-file in Python-client is equal to the proto-file in Go-server. It is crucial.

The Go allows skipping the description of unused RPC calls and messages in proto-file, while Python requires all of them.

Answer (score -3):

I ran into a similar issue, I changed the port number on the server and client side and then everything worked fine.

`server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50053')`

changing 50051 to 50053 is what worked for me.